# How do I implement a captive portal with STM32 microcontroller?

Tags: http, captiveportal

I am using my device as an Access Point and I need to display a deafault web page once somebody is connected.

Right now I have to connect to a specific `IP` (socket parameters: `IP 192.168.0.1` , `PORT 80`) to show the page.

The page doesn't need to open automatically, it just has to show up no matter what URL gets inserted in the browser.

I've read the `RFC7710` but I'm not able to implement "low level" solutions such as modify the `option 160` of the `DHCP`.

The best thing for me would be to work at the `HTTP` level.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your STM32 also the network gateway?

Comment: Yes, the network is a point to point connection. The device acts as gateway and webserver. It just has to show a configuration page in order to get and store some data.

Comment: Then it should be easy, just fake HTTP traffic and don't let anything in/out until the captive actions are successfuly taken.

Comment: The problem is that there is no HTTP traffic unless the client connects to the specific IP.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP works on the top of the TCP/IP infrastructure, it requires an established TCP connection first. As long as there is no TCP connection from the client to the HTTP server, the server has no way to tell, force, or trick a client to connect to its IP address and TCP port. No connection, no HTTP.

Comment: Thank you, I need a way to force the client on a specific socket once it is connected to WiFi. What about opening a different socket? Could it lead to a solution?